# Getting an error with the request module

Tags: api, node.js, bitcoin

I'm doing a query to the mtgox server.  Here is the API https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1. My code successfully hits the server but after a a few times this error pops up:

```
events.js:115
      listeners[i].apply(this, args);
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at EncryptedStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at SecurePair.destroy (tls.js:896:22)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't from the API call limits.

//the following function returns general ticker information in USD. This includes high, low, and volume...

```
exports.market_data = function(req, res, next){
  console.log("test");
  options = {
    uri: 'http://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/555.55 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.5.5555.55 Safari/555.55'
    }
  };
  try {
    request(options, function (err, response, body) {
      // console.log(body);
      APIResponder.respond(res, response);
    });
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("Gangnam style");
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Sorry for the delay, Internet died. Here is the code that queries MTGox. Hope this helps.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
Refers to listeners[i] - You should post that section of code, we don't know what kind of object or function that is.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? Somewhere you are binding an event handler that is `null` instead of a `function` so when it tries to run the function, it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what does your *request* function but if it's a shortcut for *http.request*, you should keep in mind that the response arrives in chunks. You do not know if you can write to **res** with the same speed as **response** gets chunks so your APIResponder.respond should pipe the response to res: res.pipe(response), or you can treat this manually:

```
response.on('data',function(data){
    var flushed = res.write(data);
    if(!flushed) response.pause();
})
res.on('drain',function(){
    response.resume();
})
```